# How to let MSAccess SUM based on Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query that keeps adding the entire Copies column instead of grouping it via Titles even though I used the GROUP BY func. Any help?

```
SELECT M.Title, SUM(S.Copies) AS TotalCopies
FROM tblMovies AS M, tblSales AS S
GROUP BY M.Title
HAVING SUM(S.Copies) > 4
;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got the answer by adding a WHERE clause that limits the ID clash from the two tables. My bad. Here's the code for anyone interested.

```
SELECT M.Title, SUM(S.Copies) AS TotalCopies
FROM tblMovies AS M, tblSales AS S
WHERE M.MovieID=S.MovieID
GROUP BY M.Title
HAVING SUM(S.Copies) > 4
;
```